# jQuery not being executed with ajax navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax

On my wordpress theme, I have a live input validation on the contact page, and also on the comment form. It's basically an ajax request to a php file doing the right things.

I've also choosen to use ajaxify (https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) to build an ajax navigation.

Both things are working, except that when used together with ajaxify, my live input validation doesn't work anymore.

You can check live demo of what I'm talking here : http://www.deenastic.com

If you navigate from the home to the contact page (link in the main menu, not the one on the top right) and enter something in one of the input, nothing happens. Then, if you refresh the page, and enther something, you will get validation working.

Here is the jQuery I made for the validation (if it helps understanding the problem) :

```
    $('#contact-form input').change(function() {

    var t = this;
    var ajaxUrl = $('#contact-form').attr('action');

    if (this.value != this.lastValue)
    {   
        if (this.timer)
            clearTimeout(this.timer); // this is to prevent ajax request being fired is someone is holding a key (it will fire when it'll be released)
        // todo: append ajax loader

        this.timer = setTimeout(function() { // Fire ajax request in 1/5 second
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxUrl,
                data: 'action=validate_'+t.name+'&data='+t.value,
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                success : function(data) {
                    if (data == 'ok')
                    {
                        var span = t.parentNode.lastChild;
                        if (span.className == 'error') // do we had an error before ?
                            t.parentNode.removeChild(span);

                        // creates our new elem
                        var icon = document.createElement('span');
                        icon.setAttribute('class', 'check');
                        icon.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
                        t.parentNode.appendChild(icon);
                        t.style.borderColor = "#1abc9c";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var span = t.parentNode.lastChild;
                        if (span.className == 'check')
                            t.parentNode.removeChild(span);

                        // creates our new elem
                        var icon = document.createElement('span');
                        icon.setAttribute('class', 'error');
                        icon.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
                        t.parentNode.appendChild(icon);
                        t.style.borderColor = "#e74c3c";    
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 200);
    }
    this.lastValue = this.value;
});
```

Comment: I recommend creating a separate form validation function, and on AJAX success, call the form validation function.

Comment: Well actually the ajaxify script is causing all my javascript not being executed. So it doesn't concern only the validation part, but also some other code I'm using for shortcodes etc...

Comment: You have to initialize the ajax validation code in the response of your https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify js

Answer (score 0):

it can be achieve by using jquery validation engine .
call jquery validation engine again on input after ajax request.
also change you change function to live change. like this:

```
 $('#contact-form input').live('change',function(){
       $(this).validate();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing

this

```
$('#contact-form input').change(function() {
```

to

```
  $(document).on('change', '#contact-form input', function(e) {
```

Thanks for the help guys